# Does FDataSnapshot implement isEqual?

Tags: objective-c, firebase

When comparing two `FDataSnapshot` values does `FDataSnapshot` implement `isEqual`?  I'm adding a `FDataSnapshot` to an `NSArray` and I want to be able to determine if it is different from the one that is already there such as through `isEqual`.

Comment: Try and see with two snapshots you know *should* be equal?

Comment: Firebases's JavaScript API has no `isEqual` method. Are you talking about the Object C wrappers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FDataSnapshot does not have an isEqual method, but you can get at the underlying value using [FDataSnapshot value] and perform your own equality check (which will depend on whether you get an array or dictionary).